# What does KB means in announce to rent apartment?

Tags: meaning, slang

I'm looking for an apartment, and in announces it's often written KB. For example :

- Suitable for one person. 2 rooms, KB, no pets allowed, no smoking allowed
- Furnished flat with more than one room, suitable for singles, families with one child, bedroom, living room, KB, internet possible not yet installed, no pets allowed no smoking allowed

It looks to have something with the kitchen, but I can't find what it could be.

Comment: Is this specific to BrE?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it's shorthand for "kitchen & bath", meaning the apartment has a kitchen and one bathroom.

Comment: Interesting that they repeated **allowed** twice, and abbreviated KB.